# Impact of size being set to columns in db

Tags: mysql, storage

I run a website with MySql db back end. I need to know what is the impact when we choose a column type (say MediumTEXT) in order to save some heavy data.
eg :

MEDIUMTEXT |    16,777,215 (224−1) bytes = 16 MiB

From above , the MEDIUMTEXT is 16,777,215 (224−1) bytes . which means it can hold up to 16Mb of data. Does this mean, it reserves 16mb data to every entry inserted?

i.e if my entry is just "Hello World", how would mysql ( or in the case any db) handle writing to the disc?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No, it doesn't reserve all that space.  It allocates 3 bytes per row to store the (future, variable) length of the actual data, and then only as much space is used as is needed to store the data for each row created.

> L represents the actual length in bytes of a given string value.
>   ...storage for a `MEDIUMTEXT` value requires L bytes to store the value plus three bytes to store the length of the value.

http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/storage-requirements.html